# Sharing directory from Windows host to Kubernetes container (using Docker Desktop)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I would like to share a directory from my Windows host to my Kubernetes container, achieving the same what I used to have in docker-compose:

```
        volumes:
            - ./data:/mnt/data
```

I tried with hostPath the following way:

```
  volumes:
  - name: data-vol
    hostPath:
      path: ./data
      type: Directory
```

It failed with "MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "data-vol" : hostPath type check failed: ./data is not a directory"

I tried with different path formats (e.g: /C/data or /host_mnt/c/data) but no success. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: I'd avoid this sort of setup in Kubernetes; once you move off a Docker Desktop-type setup, the `hostPath:` refers to the node the pod is running on, and that could change over routine upgrades and cluster maintenance.  What's actually in this directory?

Comment: Some python scripts that I want to be able to update quite regularly without rebuilding the docker image. Also there is a log directory which I like to be able to see from the host machine. Is there any better way dealing with those dirs that works on Docker Desktop as well?

Comment: For that sort of use case I might just run Python directly, without involving container technology at all.

Comment: Well the container has many other things (webserver, scheduler and a lot more) in it, it's not only about running python scripts. So container is a must

Comment: If you are using Docker desktop, is the volume that you are trying to use shared under "Shared Drives"? Did you try with Windows path, something like c:/path/to/your/dir ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use absolute path instead relative:

FROM:
path: ./data
type: Directory

TO:
path: /my/absolute/path/data
type: Directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).